# Remote Access to SQLite3 DB

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I need to be able to remotely access a sqlite3 database from over the network, while I understand this is generally bad practice, my application will only be reading from the database. And switch to something besides sqlite3 is not an option because the application that uses it is proprietary.

I see most people suggesting a network share but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to go about this, as I will only ever need access to this one file.

For those of you curious, I will be accessing Apple Configurator's backend database that stores device information if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that [SQL Relay](http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/about.html) might be exactly what you need.

It provides network access to many databases, [sqlite3](http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/sqlrelay/gettingstarted/sqlite.html) included.